# Does SOAP spec allow non-xml content between headers and envelope

Tags: xml, http, soap

Is the following allowed according to the SOAP spec?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"

000 OK.
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
       <m:GetLastTradePriceResponse xmlns:m="Some-URI">
            <Price>34.5</Price>
       </m:GetLastTradePriceResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Note the "000 OK." I can't find anything about it in the official spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the spec says that the payload needs to be XML. This is not XML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.. But you can add custom header to enclose that data.

Comment: I don't want to enclose that data. I receive such a reply from a webservice and I wonder whether it's a correct reply or not.